# wp_cache_get not working in wp_head hook

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have been using wp_cache functionality in my website for improve performance for home page and avoid multiple query.

i have put code into my function.php like below,

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'set_data_in_cache' );

function set_data_in_cache(){
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        gloabl $wpdb;
        $dataInCache = wp_cache_get('post_data');           
        if( $dataInCache === false ){
            $result  = $wpdb->query('some query');
            wp_cache_set('post_data',$result,'',86400);         
        }
        else{
            //data in cache
        }
    }
}
```

I have been checking, every time on page load, $dataInCache variable is empty. means no data being stored in cache.
it should not be empty once page load and set data in to cache.

But $dataInCache = wp_cache_get('post_data'); working perfectly inside body tag and data is being displaying perfectly.

Is that anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you tried with "init" action?

Comment: actually you are not getting the post data at the start of the file which is wp_head

Comment: in 'init' hook i can not set front page so need to use wp_head hook

Comment: @ahmed: i am getting post data in wp_head hook and it is displaying successfully in page, but as i told you it not storing in cache

Comment: i want , when i refresh page , every time query should not run but get data from cache and display on page.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use force to be true inside wp_cache_get to get the result.

```
wp_cache_get( $key, '', true );
```

Also it will be good to define a group and then get the cache , so that it will be available in the head.